# Grommet: Top and Bottom Tab activate the same content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grommet

I'm wondering is there a way to set Tabs top and Bottom to display the tabs content using grommet tabs component:

example of what I am looking to do can be seen in the image below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6YES.jpg

I have a sample codepen with a quick mock up.

```
code can be found in the codepen
```

http://codepen.io/Niall_Maher/pen/pProXW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not really a component that can do it, but you can add a second line of tabs with empty content that syncs with the first tabs and backwards, thanks to this properties on both tabs:

```
activeIndex={this.state.selectedIndex} 
onActive={i=>this.setState({selectedIndex:i})}
```

Checkout this:
[image]

Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/MarcoMedrano/pen/jmLWwZ?editors=0010) (: